# Converting date in JSON and displaying it in a DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, datatable

I have a local JSON file that's being rendered into a DataTable. Everything in the table is fine except the dates are rendered like this: `/Date(1350028800000)/` (10/12/2012).

I looked up [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date) about converting the data but based on how information is rendered into a DataTable I'm not sure how I would proceed. Any thoughts on this one?

#### JS snippet:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import admissData from '../JSON/atty-admiss.json';
import DataTable from 'datatables.net';

function loadAdmiss() {
    let admissText = admissData.d.results.map(function(val) {
        return {
            "Status": val.admissionstatus,
            // "Date of Admission": val.dateofadmission,
            "Expires": val.expires,
            "Classification": val.classification
        }
    })
    let admissDate = admissData.d.results.map(function(val) {
        let newDate = new Date(admissDate) { //// ?
            return val.dateofadmission
        }
    })

    $('#admissions-table').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { data: "Status" },
            { data: "Date of Admission" }, // ------ DT's method of injecting relevant JSON data into each column
            { data: "Expires" },
            { data: "Classification" }
        ],
        data: admissText, // ---------- how the JSON data enters DT
        lengthChange: false,
        paging: true,
        pagingType: "full_numbers"
    });

}

loadAdmiss();
```

Comment: What is your actual question? The referenced post shows how to convert an MS JSON date to an ECMAScript Date. Are you asking how to apply that to your code?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

```
var admissData = {
    d: {
        results: [
            '/Date(1350028800000)/',
            '/Date(1550185211515)/',
        ]
    }
};


var parseMicorsoftFormat = function(weirdDateFormat) {
    if(typeof weirdDateFormat === 'string') { //lets assume we have a string to work with 
        var extractedData = !!weirdDateFormat.match(/\d+/g) ? weirdDateFormat.match(/\d+/g)[0] : null;
        if(extractedData) {
            return new Date(parseInt(extractedData)).toLocaleString().match(/[^,]*/)[0];
        }else {
            return "No numbers found"
        }
    }else {
        return "Wrong Format"
    }
};

admissData.d.results = admissData.d.results.map(date => parseMicorsoftFormat(date));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.